# How do I implement this in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: This bottom bar that is scrollable horizonatally]

I have tried BottomNavigationBar but it requires an Icon.

This instead is text only, sort of represents analytics history and it's scrollable.

Comment: You can use your own custom widget instead of `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: Why dont you try it by yourself, you can simply use `Container` or there are lot of options, Do some search.

Comment: you can use size property of icon and set to 0.0. i think this is the easiest solution for you Issue if it is OK for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bottom bar you could make your own custom widget like this:

```
Container(
  height: 80.0,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: List.generate(10, (int index) {
      return new Text("$index");
    }),
  ),
),
```

Replace the children with actual children that you want for the `ListView` and adjust its wrapping to have a height that suits your need and there you go

Comment: nice, I think I can continue from here. Thanks!